# How can I find_package() with different build trees?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to follow the modern cmake path and use the find_packages()/link libraries way.

I am using a test scenario in which:
LIB_B depends on LIB_A and EXEC_A depends on both.

I was wondering how you could link EXEC_A to the debug lib version of LIB_B and the release version of LIB_A or vice versa.

On LIB_A I am using `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "-debug")` so my LIB_A is going to be LIB_A-debug when making the debug tree. I install them in /usr/local/lib and both reside there.

For example let's say I have this line of code in LIB_A:

```
#ifdef Release
 printf("THIS IS RELEASE MODE");
#endif
```

This is going to differentiate LIB_A and LIB_A-debug.

in EXEC_A I would use

```
find_package(LIBA REQUIRED)
add_executable(EXEC_A main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(EXEC_A PUBLIC LIBS::LIBA LIBS::LIBB)
```

assuming I have exported the libraries in the LIBS namespace.

Is there any way to differentiate between library versions?

EDIT: I am on Linux (centos) and using GCC 8. My CMake version is 3.14

Comment: What is your underlying development environment(OS/Compiler etc.)?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not including that. I edited the original post

Comment: Are  LIB_A and LIB_B part of the same source tree as EXEC_A, or are they compiled and installed from a separate source tree?

Comment: @John they are compiled and installed entirely independently